Does it affect performance to have nginx configs of sites which are currently not visited?
I'm using ngnix for my local setup, I have multiple websites/projects that I work on and I have it configured under sites-enabled. When I'm working on a single website/project I don't need other websites to work but since I just do sudo systemctl restart nginx, I'm thinking I make every website active to listening for request all the time? Or nginx only starts working when I have make request to a website that I'm currently on? I'm concerned about the performance. Do I have to automate enabling sites depending on the projects with a bash script or something?

See how Nginx processes a request. So Nginx is listening for a request then decides which website configuration to use to process it. There is probably a small memory impact but probably insignificant.

In addition to what Richard has already said, an algorithm used to choose the server block to process the request is almost the same that is used for the map directive with hostnames keyword enabled. You can read about its performance here. In short, unless you have a couple of server blocks with regexes used as server_name directive parameters, there isn't any performance impact. @RichardSmith This may be of interest to you as well.
